# requirement failed: Provided Maven Coordinates must be in the form 'groupId:artifactId:version'

Tags: scala, sbt, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, spark-streaming, snowflake-connector

I get the following error

> requirement failed: Provided Maven Coordinates must be in the form
> 'groupId:artifactId:version'

when I run the command below

```
spark-submit --class StreamHandler\
--master local[*]\
--packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.4.5,\
  net.snowflake.snowflake-ingest-sdk:0.10.3,\
  net.snowflake.snowflake-jdbc.3.13.14\
  target/scala-2.11/stream-handler_2.11-1.0.jar
```

I am trying to consume data using scala and push it to a snowflake sink database. My build.sbt file looks like this

```
name := "Stream Handler"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.12"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.4.5" % "provided",
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.4.5" % "provided",
    "net.snowflake" % "snowflake-ingest-sdk" % "0.10.3",
    "net.snowflake" % "snowflake-jdbc" % "3.13.14",
    "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-core" % "1.2.0"
    //"net.snowflake" % "spark-snowflake" % "2.7.2"
  
  )
```

Anyone here who has encountered this and can help?

Comment: No idea if that's the reason but the args you are passing to `--packages` does not match the format `groupId:artifactId:version`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to specify the packages for Snowflake is:

not:

```
net.snowflake.snowflake-ingest-sdk:0.10.3
```

but:

```
net.snowflake:snowflake-ingest-sdk:0.10.3
```

where:

```
<groupId>net.snowflake</groupId>
<artifactId>snowflake-ingest-sdk</artifactId>
<version>0.10.3</version>
```

Same for JDBC:

```
net.snowflake:snowflake-jdbc:3.13.14
```